# When should one event listener be used and when should multiple ones be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm kind of confused as to what is the best option, performance-wise, when using event listeners (using jQuery for that), in these kind of cases.

**Case 1**:
Say you have a div that contains two inputs, and you want to "listen" to both, for a **keyUp** event. (this div is the only thing in the document, and its height and width is also that of the full document)

```
        <div id=formContainer>
            <input type="text" id="a">
            <input type="text" id="b">
        </div>
```

What would be better? : Attaching a 'delegated event listener'  to **formContainer** or attaching an event listener to **each input**?

**Case 2**:
Now, say you have an html structure like this (again, chatContainer is full height and width of document, and it, and its children, are only thing in it)

```
   <div id=chatContainer>

     <div id="menu"></div> //Has to listen to clicks for interactivity
     <div id="messagesWindow"></div> //Has to listen to clicks on every message appended
     <input type="text" id="inputSomething"> //Has to listen to keyUp events

   </div>
```

In this case, is it better to attach an event listener to every div/input or to attach all needed event listeners to **chatContainer (keyUp, click)**?

I have read up on delegated events, but I don't know if I got it right. I would just like to do what's better, even if the performance difference is small.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Adding events directly - performance hit is when you are  attaching the event. Delegated events - performance hit is when the event is triggered. What is better to use depends on the actual code.

Comment: In such a small context either one is acceptable. If you're triggered events use the same function when the `keyUp` is fired there is no problem attaching them upon creation to the parent div. Performance issues only creep into your application when you have alot (1000 >), do ALOT of DOM modification (garbage collection issue at that point), or when you have a very large memory consuming function tied to the event.

Comment: Also https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md is a great read for getting started with Javascript and optimization. I highly recommend it.

Comment: That was a good read, thank you, and I realize the context matters more when it gets more complex, in that sense it seems clear, but otherwise the answer isn't very intuitive for me. Epascarello, alright, so, what about the memory it takes to attach many events at once vs only one? I'm thinking of event listening as maybe something that's stored in RAM and can get quite heavy, or is that a completely wrong point of view? When it is triggered it consumes CPU power, but surely the 'listening' is stored in RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also didn't know which is faster(even if the difference is small).So I wrote the test code

**code written by coffeescript**

they are compiled code though you can see javascript code at jsfiddle.

**case 1** http://jsfiddle.net/5mnroam3/

(your question case)

```
<div id=formContainer>
    <input type="text" id="a">
    <input type="text" id="b">
</div>

counterA = counterB = 0
$("#formContainer").click( (e) ->
  switch $(e.target).attr("id")
    when "a"
      counterA++
    when "b"
      counterB++
)
startTime = new Date()
for i in [0...10000]
  $("#a").trigger("click")
  $("#b").trigger("click")
endTime = new Date() - startTime
console.log("listen to container : #{endTime} ms","counterA is #{counterA}","counterB is #{counterB}")

counterA = counterB = 0
$("#formContainer").off("click")
$("#a").click((e) ->
  counterA++
)
$("#b").click((e) ->
  counterB++
)
startTime = new Date()
for i in [0...10000]
  $("#a").trigger("click")
  $("#b").trigger("click")
endTime = new Date() - startTime
console.log("listen to each elem : #{endTime} ms","counterA is #{counterA}","counterB is #{counterB}")
```

code above is doing 10000times click on both "#a" and "#b" and doing "counter++" everytime the event's occurred.
in my macbook(MBP2013mid chrome latest), the result was

```
listen to container : 2224 ms counterA is 10000 counterB is 10000

listen to each elem : 1952 ms counterA is 10000 counterB is 10000
```

listening each elem is bit faster.

**case 2** http://jsfiddle.net/fbjyp5yL/

(Case target element has an child element which means when you listen to outer element,you have to check if the clicked element has the target elements as its parent or not because `e.target` or `this` in the event callback function is always most inner element you can click)

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="element1">
    <div class="children1"></div>
    <div class="children2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="element2">
    <div class="children1"></div>
    <div class="children2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

counterA = counterB = 0

$("#outer").click( (e) ->
  if $(e.target).closest("#element1").length
    counterA++
  else if $(e.target).closest("#element2").length
    counterB++
  else
    console.log("unexpected event")
)
startTime = new Date()
for i in [0...5000]
  $("#element1 .children1").trigger("click")
  $("#element1 .children2").trigger("click")
  $("#element2 .children1").trigger("click")
  $("#element2 .children2").trigger("click")
endTime = new Date() - startTime
console.log("listen to outer : #{endTime} ms",counterA,counterB)

$("#outer").off("click")
counterA = counterB = 0
$("#element1 .children1,#element1 .children2").click( (e) ->
  counterA++
)
$("#element2 .children1,#element2 .children2").click( (e) ->
  counterB++
)
startTime = new Date()
for i in [0...5000]
  $("#element1 .children1").trigger("click")
  $("#element1 .children2").trigger("click")
  $("#element2 .children1").trigger("click")
  $("#element2 .children2").trigger("click")
endTime = new Date() - startTime
console.log("listen to each elem : #{endTime} ms",counterA,counterB)
```

in this case, my result was

```
listen to outer : 2547 ms 10000 10000

listen to each elem : 2159 ms 10000 10000
```

So listening outer element is slower just like case 1 and the difference is bigger than case1 even though it's just 300-400ms through 20000times click.

**conclusion**

listening an event on each div/input is faster though the difference between using outer or each inner elems is small.and I'm sure if there are 10 or 20 inner elements,the difference is still small enough.so choose on your favor whichever you like.

Comment: Cool test, I also learnt something new from your code. I guess that this measures the CPU response for each method, in a way, but the amount of memory each one consumes is also important, isn't it? Is there a way to measure such a thing with a test like this? (Again, I don't know if I'm getting this memory/cpu thing correctly!). Thank you very much, I might as well choose this as an answer since you took the effort and it proves a point.